# CSS Fitting/Position Issue (Fitting to page regardless of monitor size)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an interactive bell schedule for my school and I have tried and tried to explore the various values for `position`, `float`, `left/right`, `margin`, etc., and I cannot figure out how to make the tables (overview of schedules) fit so it will always fit on the page, and not overflow off the side. I'm trying to keep it as user-friendly as possible and not require teachers to know how to zoom out on a browser to see everything. Sometimes it will fit, for example on my Chromebook OS it will fit just fine. But on my Windows desktop, it will appear a bit too big. I'm not trying to mess with too many exact values for positioning, so what's the easiest way to do this?

## Things I've Tried

*Changing the position of the `bell1` and `bell2` divs in the HTML file to outside the `container` div, outside the `body` div, and leaving it where it's at

*Getting rid of `float`, or `position`, or both, or changing it to `position: relative;` and doing the same troubleshooting with various values

*Forcing percentage scales (50% for example)

## Preview

[image: current preview]

## Code snippet

```js
//Not sure it's necessary to add the javascript, since it has no HTML DOM regarding style (it only involves the time and clock settings), but I'll add an excerpt just incase
function clock() {
  /*global hr*/
  /*global min*/
  var time = new Date();
  // hr is set to be 24 hours, aka 1 pm becomes 13
  var hr = time.getHours();
  var min = time.getMinutes();

  var ampm = " PM";
  if (hr < 12) {
    ampm = " AM";
  }
  // since hr is 24 hour time, we make it 12 hour time by subtracting 12 from it if its above twelve
  if (hr > 12) {
    hr -= 12;
  }
  if (hr < 10) {
    hr = "" + hr;
  }
  // if the minute value is under 10, add a 0 before it so it shows as 2:05 instead of 2:5
  if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + min;
  }
  // set the text of the "Current Time" to the current time
  document.getElementById("timetext").value = hr + ":" + min + ampm;
  // refresh this function every 1 second, or 1000 milliseconds, to update time
  setTimeout("clock()", 1000);

}

function setPeriod() {
  //set elements from webpage as variables
  var current = document.getElementById("timetext");
  var period = document.getElementById("periodtext");
  var per1 = document.getElementById("p1");
  var per2 = document.getElementById("p2");
  var per3 = document.getElementById("p3");
  var per4 = document.getElementById("p4");
  var per5 = document.getElementById("p5");
  var adv = document.getElementById("adv");
  var per6 = document.getElementById("p6");
  var per7 = document.getElementById("p7");
  var thur = document.getElementById("thur");
  var revis = document.getElementById("revis");
  // add a listener to the thursday button if it is checked/unchecked
  thur.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // if thursday is checked after being clicked
    if (thur.checked == true && revis.checked == false) {
      // disable the advisory button
      adv.disabled = true;
      // if the period 1 button is checked...
      if (per1.checked == true) {
        // ... set the text to the time period 1 starts and ends on a thursday
        period.value = "8:50 AM - 9:33 AM";
      }
      // repeat the process for the other periods
      else if (per2.checked == true) {
        period.value = "9:38 AM - 10:21 AM";
      } else if (per3.checked == true) {
        period.value = "10:26 AM - 11:09 AM";
      } else if (per4.checked == true) {
        period.value = "11:09 AM - 12:36 PM";
      } else if (per5.checked == true) {
        period.value = "12:41 PM - 1:24 PM";
      } else if (adv.checked == true) {
        alert("Period Selection is reset due to Thursday-mode being enabled whilst Advisory is selected");
        adv.checked = false;
        period.value = "Select Period";
      } else if (per6.checked == true) {
        period.value = "1:28 PM - 2:12 PM";
      } else if (per7.checked == true) {
        period.value = "2:17 PM - 3:00 PM";
      } else {
        console.log("User tried enabling Thursday mode with no period selected!");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}

.textHeader {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: impact;
  text-shadow: #f00 1px 1px;
}

table {
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}

img {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}

#credits {
  text-align: center;
}

#bell1 {
  display: inline-table;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 100%;
  width: 350px;
  left: -375px;
}

#bell2 {
  display: inline-table;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
  width: 350px;
  right: -375px;
}

#norm,
#norm2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lunch {
  background-color: silver;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  font-size: 115%;
}

.textLabel {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: impact;
  text-align: center;
}

.textImp,
.textSub {
  font-size: 110%;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.textImp {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 0, 0) 1px 1px;
  font-style: bold;
}

.text {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-family: courier;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #f00;
}

c #periodButtons {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 125%;
}

#currentPeriod,
#currentLunch,
#currentTime {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>City High Bell Schedule</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="city_high_bell_schedule.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif">
  <script src="city_high_bell_schedule.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="clock();">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="body">
      <div id="bell1">
        <h2 id="norm" class="textImp">Normal</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>MTWF</th>
            <th>TH</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 1</td>
            <td>8:50-9:39</td>
            <td>8:50-9:33</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 2</td>
            <td>9:44-10:33</td>
            <td>9:38-10:21</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 3</td>
            <td>10:38-11:27</td>
            <td>10:26-11:09</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 4</td>
            <td>11:27-12:52</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>A LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
            <td>11:27-11:55<br>12:00-12:52</td>
            <td>11:09-11:39<br>11:44-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>CLASS<br>B LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
            <td>11:32-11:55<br>11:55-12:23<br>12:25-12:52</td>
            <td>11:14-11:39<br>11:39-12:07<br>12:11-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>CLASS<br>C LUNCH</td>
            <td>11:32-12:24<br>12:24-12:52</td>
            <td>11:14-12:05<br>12:07-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 5</td>
            <td>12:57-1:46</td>
            <td>12:41-1:24</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Advisory</td>
            <td>1:46-2:12</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 6</td>
            <td>2:17-3:06</td>
            <td>1:28-2:12</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 7</td>
            <td>3:11-4:00</td>
            <td>2:17-3:00</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="bell2">
        <h2 id="norm2" class="textImp">Revised</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>MTWF</th>
            <th>TH</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 1</td>
            <td>8:45-9:37</td>
            <td>8:45-9:31</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 2</td>
            <td>9:42-10:32</td>
            <td>9:36-10:20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 3</td>
            <td>10:37-11:27</td>
            <td>10:25-11:09</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 4</td>
            <td>11:27-12:52</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>A LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
            <td>11:27-11:55<br>12:00-12:52</td>
            <td>11:09-11:39<br>11:44-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>CLASS<br>B LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
            <td>11:32-11:55<br>11:55-12:23<br>12:25-12:52</td>
            <td>11:14-11:39<br>11:39-12:07<br>12:11-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lunch">
            <td>CLASS<br>C LUNCH</td>
            <td>11:32-12:24<br>12:24-12:52</td>
            <td>11:14-12:05<br>12:07-12:36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 5</td>
            <td>12:57-1:48</td>
            <td>12:41-1:27</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Advisory</td>
            <td>1:48-2:15</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 6</td>
            <td>2:20-3:10</td>
            <td>1:32-2:16</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Period 7</td>
            <td>3:15-4:05</td>
            <td>2:21-3:05</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="textHeader">City High Bell Schedule</h4>
    <p class="textSub">This is a timer/clock that automatically updates what the current period is, what time the period begins and ends, plus an overview of the schedule itself. It is meant to be put on a smartboard during work time, reading time, whatever it may be. So
      students can stop asking, "What time does this period end?"<br></p>
    <p class="textImp">THE TEACHER DISMISSES THE CLASS, NOT THE BELL OR THIS REFERENCE.</p>
    <p class="textSub" style="text-align: center;"><b>Instructions:</b> Select the current period, and this page *should* do the rest for you.</p>
    <div id="schedule">
      <p class="textLabel">Current Time</p>
      <div id="currentTime">
        <input type="button" value="Loading..." id="timetext" class="text" />
      </div>
      <p class="textLabel">Current Period</p>
      <div id="currentPeriod">
        <input type="button" value="Select Period" id="periodtext" class="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="periodButtons" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="p1" type="radio" name="per" />Period 1
        <input id="p2" type="radio" name="per" />Period 2
        <input id="p3" type="radio" name="per" />Period 3
        <input id="p4" type="radio" name="per" />Period 4
        <input id="p5" type="radio" name="per" />Period 5
        <input id="adv" type="radio" name="per" />Advisory
        <input id="p6" type="radio" name="per" />Period 6
        <input id="p7" type="radio" name="per" />Period 7
        <br>
        <input id="thur" type="checkbox" />Thursday
        <input id="revis" type="checkbox" checked="true" />Revised Schedule (2018/2019)
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="footer">
        <p id="credits">
          Made by Josh Brenneman
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## RECAP

How do I, in CSS, make it so no matter the monitor size, if the webpage is at 100% zoom (aka default zoom), how do I make the tables (`bell1/bell2`) always fit so there's no scrollbar and the tables will align with each side?

Comment: Sorry, it's not too clear what you want to achieve. You want everything fits horizontally, vertically or both? the middle column should have a fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your floated and absolute-positioned elements. I suggest you use flex in aligning your elements. Don't use absolute position when the element has no  relative-positioned parent. Check the code

```css
#container {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}

#container .column {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#container .column.table{
    width: 70%;
}

.textHeader {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: impact;
    text-shadow: #f00 1px 1px;
}


table {
    background: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: solid 2px #000;
}
img {
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
}
#credits {
    text-align: center;
}

#bell1 {
    display: inline-table;

}
#bell2 {
    display: inline-table;

}
#norm, #norm2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 0px;
}
tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.lunch {
    background-color: silver;
}

td,
th {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
    font-size: 115%;
}

.textLabel {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: impact;
    text-align: center;
}

.textImp,
.textSub {
    font-size: 110%;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
}

.textImp {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 0, 0) 1px 1px;
    font-style: bold;
}

.text {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
    font-family: courier;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #f00;
}
c
#periodButtons {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 125%;
}

#currentPeriod,
#currentLunch,
#currentTime {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>City High Bell Schedule</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="city_high_bell_schedule.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif">
    <script src="city_high_bell_schedule.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
            <div class="column table">
              <h2 id="norm" class="textImp">Normal</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Period</th>
                        <th>MTWF</th>
                        <th>TH</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 1</td>
                        <td>8:50-9:39</td>
                        <td>8:50-9:33</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 2</td>
                        <td>9:44-10:33</td>
                        <td>9:38-10:21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 3</td>
                        <td>10:38-11:27</td>
                        <td>10:26-11:09</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 4</td>
                        <td>11:27-12:52</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>A LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
                        <td>11:27-11:55<br>12:00-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:09-11:39<br>11:44-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>CLASS<br>B LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
                        <td>11:32-11:55<br>11:55-12:23<br>12:25-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:14-11:39<br>11:39-12:07<br>12:11-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>CLASS<br>C LUNCH</td>
                        <td>11:32-12:24<br>12:24-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:14-12:05<br>12:07-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 5</td>
                        <td>12:57-1:46</td>
                        <td>12:41-1:24</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Advisory</td>
                        <td>1:46-2:12</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 6</td>
                        <td>2:17-3:06</td>
                        <td>1:28-2:12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 7</td>
                        <td>3:11-4:00</td>
                        <td>2:17-3:00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        <div class="column">
         <h4 class="textHeader">City High Bell Schedule</h4>
         <p class="textSub">This is a timer/clock that automatically updates what the current period is, what time the period begins and ends, plus an overview of the schedule itself. It is meant to be put on a smartboard during work time,
             reading time, whatever it may be. So students can stop asking, "What time does this period end?"<br></p>
         <p class="textImp">THE TEACHER DISMISSES THE CLASS, NOT THE BELL OR THIS REFERENCE.</p>
         <p class="textSub" style="text-align: center;"><b>Instructions:</b> Select the current period, and this page *should* do the rest for you.</p>

          <p class="textLabel">Current Time</p>
            <div id="currentTime">
                <input type="button" value="Loading..." id="timetext" class="text" />
            </div>
            <p class="textLabel">Current Period</p>
            <div id="currentPeriod">
                <input type="button" value="Select Period" id="periodtext" class="text" />
            </div>
            <div id="periodButtons" style="text-align: center;">
                <input id="p1" type="radio" name="per" />Period 1
                <input id="p2" type="radio" name="per" />Period 2
                <input id="p3" type="radio" name="per" />Period 3
                <input id="p4" type="radio" name="per" />Period 4
                <input id="p5" type="radio" name="per" />Period 5
                <input id="adv" type="radio" name="per" />Advisory
                <input id="p6" type="radio" name="per" />Period 6
                <input id="p7" type="radio" name="per" />Period 7
                <br>
                <input id="thur" type="checkbox" />Thursday
                <input id="revis" type="checkbox" checked="true"/>Revised Schedule (2018/2019)
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="footer">
                <p id="credits">
                    Made by Josh Brenneman
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
             <div class="column table">
            <h2 id="norm2" class="textImp">Revised</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Period</th>
                        <th>MTWF</th>
                        <th>TH</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 1</td>
                        <td>8:45-9:37</td>
                        <td>8:45-9:31</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 2</td>
                        <td>9:42-10:32</td>
                        <td>9:36-10:20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 3</td>
                        <td>10:37-11:27</td>
                        <td>10:25-11:09</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 4</td>
                        <td>11:27-12:52</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>A LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
                        <td>11:27-11:55<br>12:00-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:09-11:39<br>11:44-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>CLASS<br>B LUNCH<br>CLASS</td>
                        <td>11:32-11:55<br>11:55-12:23<br>12:25-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:14-11:39<br>11:39-12:07<br>12:11-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lunch">
                        <td>CLASS<br>C LUNCH</td>
                        <td>11:32-12:24<br>12:24-12:52</td>
                        <td>11:14-12:05<br>12:07-12:36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 5</td>
                        <td>12:57-1:48</td>
                        <td>12:41-1:27</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Advisory</td>
                        <td>1:48-2:15</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 6</td>
                        <td>2:20-3:10</td>
                        <td>1:32-2:16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period 7</td>
                        <td>3:15-4:05</td>
                        <td>2:21-3:05</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In your responsive CSS code. Just set the flex-direction value to 'column' if you want to give each element a 100% width.